# Manga: a boy suffers an accident and after waking in hospital his vision gets better and no longer needs glasses to see

Tags: story-identification, manga, horror

A boy suffers an accident and after waking in hospital his vision gets better and no longer needs glasses to see. Downside of that is that he is now able to see strange shapes instead of human heads, these strange humans are gifted with animal abilities and mostly are abrasive murderers, he is joined by 3 girls who are hunting these monsters.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Can you describe the appearance of any of the characters or remember their names?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds exactly like [Deathtopia](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=110116).

> After an incident that left Kou Fujimara grievously injured; losing sight from both eyes, the college student undergoes surgery and miraculously survives. However, this event significantly changes Kou's life, as he gains extrasensory perception abilities. Soon, a woman appears, and the boy's life changes overnight.

I've read the series a long time ago and immediately recognized it, but I couldn't remember the title. I found it again thanks to this [answer on Anime StackExchange](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/20146), which was a top search result.

Comment: Thank you so so much I loved this way more than it could be healthy. Arigato.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking: [Hanada shônen-shi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanada_Sh%C5%8Dnen_Shi), a manga written and illustrated by Makoto Isshiki.

[image: cover] cover of first issue

> 10-year-old Ichiro Hanada is in a traffic accident, and after recovering he can see ghosts. The ghosts cause comedy, but also help him find out about events involving his parents before he was born. And what happened to the father of his best friend, Sota.

Later made into a movie:
[image: poster]

It has been a long time since I saw the movie, so I do not remember if there were three girls helping him.